# How to pull multiple data/page from a static payload file and combine them as a result using DataWeave

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, payload

I hope someone sees my post and please do help me to solve this.
I am just wondering if there is a very simple code that can solve this using DataWeave.

I have this static payload being used

```
[
{
  "products": [
    {
      "code": "2698791-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/268791-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 679.00,
        "formattedValue": "679,00 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 1 Pro",
      "friendlyName": "Pro"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "products": [
    {
      "code": "9696379-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/966379-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 2.90,
        "formattedValue": "2,90 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 2 Ultra",
      "friendlyName": "Ultra"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "products": [
    {
      "code": "9696377-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/966377-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 72.90,
        "formattedValue": "72,90 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 3 Plus",
      "friendlyName": "Plus"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

This is my code and it is a working code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var id = "1234"
var code = "9696379-01"

var idObj = {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "id": id
    }


var productObj = payload
var fileData = productObj filter ((item, index) -> item.products.code == [code]) 
 

---
idObj ++ fileData[0]
```

If using only one "code" (see the code value), the result will be

```
{
  "currency": "EUR",
  "id": "1234",
  "products": [
    {
      "code": "9696379-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/966379-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 2.90,
        "formattedValue": "2,90 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 2 Ultra",
      "friendlyName": "Ultra"
    }
  ]
}
```

But, if the "code" will have multiple values like this `var code = "2698791-01, 9696379-01, 9696377-01"`

This should be the result:

````
{
  "currency": "EUR",
  "id": "1234",
  "products": [
    {
      "code": "2698791-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/268791-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 679.00,
        "formattedValue": "679,00 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 1 Pro",
      "friendlyName": "Pro"
    },
    {
      "code": "9696379-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/966379-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 2.90,
        "formattedValue": "2,90 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 2 Ultra",
      "friendlyName": "Ultra"
    },
    {
      "code": "9696377-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/966377-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 72.90,
        "formattedValue": "72,90 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 3 Plus",
      "friendlyName": "Plus"
    }

  ]
}```

Can someone help me please to solve this problem?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts assumes a single code in the condition. For a list you can change the condition to 'list of valid codes contain the code in the payload'. It can be implemented using the function `contains()`.

I'm assuming that since `products` is an array there could be more than one product in it, then every product must have a valid code. Change the condition of the filter if the assumption is wrong. I used the `every()` function from the Arrays module.

I also put the list of codes as an Array instead of a String. If you must use the string for some reason then use `splitBy()` to separate the codes into an Array.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var id = "1234"
var code = ["2698791-01", "9696379-01", "9696377-01"]

var idObj = {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "id": id
    }

var fileData = 
    payload 
        filter ((item, index) -> 
            item.products every(code contains $.code ) // assuming more than one product in products then every product must have a valid code. 
        ) 
        flatMap ($.products)
---
idObj ++ { products: fileData }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script. Let me know if this helps.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  currency: "EUR",
  id: "1234",
  products: payload flatMap $.products
}
```

Output will be as below.

```
{
  "currency": "EUR",
  "id": "1234",
  "products": [
    {
      "code": "2698791-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/268791-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 679,
        "formattedValue": "679,00 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 1 Pro",
      "friendlyName": "Pro"
    },
    {
      "code": "9696379-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/966379-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 2.9,
        "formattedValue": "2,90 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 2 Ultra",
      "friendlyName": "Ultra"
    },
    {
      "code": "9696377-01",
      "url": "https://www.product.com/966377-01.png",
      "basePrice": {
        "value": 72.9,
        "formattedValue": "72,90 €"
      },
      "name": "Product 3 Plus",
      "friendlyName": "Plus"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Harsha for your inputs, but if you notice I have a condition, that is based on the code values, if 1 value is set, then only one page will be returned based on the code value as well, if I have 2 codes, i will have the corresponding pages in the result, so on so fort, I need to include that condition to get the right set of pages/data